# Google maps showing incorrect KMZ info

Tags: google-maps

I have a small Google maps app here:

http://projects.kleelof.com/stockfight/project_view.php

It is referencing this KMZ file:

http://projects.kleelof.com/stockfight/kmz_maps/map_2.kmz

THE KMZ file is for some data in South America, yet the Google maps app is showing something in Canada.

This is the script I am using:

```
var the_map         = $('#map_canvas');
    function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.33, -98.52),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        /*
        the_map.gmap();
        the_map.gmap({
                        'callback': function() {
                                                the_map.gmap('loadKML', 'dog_feed_1', 'http://projects.kleelof.com/stockfight/kmz_maps/map_1.kmz');
                                                }
        });
        */

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var road = new google.maps.KmlLayer( 
            'http://projects.kleelof.com/stockfight/kmz_maps/map_2.kmz',
            {preserveViewport:true}
            );
        road.setMap(map);

      }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Am I missing something?

lee

Comment: [works for me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoA.html?filename=http://projects.kleelof.com/stockfight/kmz_maps/map_2.kmz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the {preserveViewport:true} option to KmlLayer tells it to not zoom to the contents of the KML, it stays at the place you initialize the map to. If you want it to go to the KMZ, remove that (or set it to false).

Comment: Thanks. Do you by chance know how to select specific layers?

Comment: Not sure what that means (you only have one in your code), but if you mean with checkboxes, search SO and/or the [Google Maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3), that has been asked a numder of times

Comment: Not sure if it is the same thing. If you noticed in the maps I used, it has different markers such as red and yellow triangles. In Google earth, I can just select the ones I want to display. Are these called groups?

Comment: Have you seen how [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fprojects.kleelof.com%2Fstockfight%2Fkmz_maps%2Fmap_2.kmz&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.641638,0.883026&t=m&z=17) displays your KMZ?

Comment: Yes. It seems to be displaying properly. The thing is only certain data needs to be displayed. Going and removing the data from the KMZ is not really possible because we have thousands of these. So, instead, I would just like to display specific layers. I figure something like this must be possible because in Google Earth, you can select the layers.